# Bound on the number of intersection points of two parameterized curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

I have come across the following problem, which may have a well known answer, but I was unable to locate one.

Consider two parameterized curves given by 
$$F(t)=(f_1(t), \dots, f_n(t), \quad G(t)= ( g_1(t), \dots, g_n(t)),$$
 where $f_i(t)$ and $g_i(t)$ are polynomials of degree at most d. Assume that the Zariski closures of the images of $F$ and $G$ (which are irreducible varieties of dimension at most one) are distinct.

Is there a bound depending on d and n for the number of intersection points of the image of $F$ and the image of $G$?

Of course, when these curves are planar we have Bezout’s theorem. There seem to be results of similar flavor in intersection, but cannot find an exact statement. I would highly appreciate if someone could point me to the right reference.

Comment: Bezout’s theorem still applies: just project to a generic plane. You cannot do better than that just because your curves might happen to be planar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linearly project both curves to generic linearly embedded projective planes and apply Bezout's theorem to get an upper bound of $d^2$. You can't do better, since the curves could lie in a linearly embedded projective plane and have $d^2$ intersection points.

Comment: Take an algebraic extension first, to be sure that there is a linear projection that doesn't identify any two of the intersection points.